# A Windows 10 fault with file permissions

Tags: permissions

Not sure if the question has arisen in this form before. I've just upgraded to Windows10 on my desktop (an HP PAvilion23) and found that file permissions were changed to read/execute; writing and updating not allowed. It's possible to rest permissions easily enough, using the Properties option on folders, and I've done that. I clears the problem for the session, but one you turn off and reboot, the original fault re-occurs. I'm the PC administrator and there is a single User login. There's a thread on the Windows help forum which suggests loads of solutions, but they all involve resetting permissions (and for me, they work only for the session; power off kills them). Here's the link.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/folder-and-file-permissions-changed-in-windows-10/38bb51a5-8cfb-4349-b635-0fdae1287eb0?page=1&auth=1

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you use a Microsoft account to log in to your computer you need to verify it against the computer.
See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/959120/windows-10-file-system-permissions-itunes-folder-locked/959126#959126)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem with permissions resetting on startup.  I struggled with this and the solution that finally worked for me, using home edition of windows 10, was the following.  One Drive was causing the problem.  I right clicked the one drive icon in the system tray and changed the setting so it wouldn't run on startup.  Reboot.  Go into File Explorer.  Highlight the directories with files that are used such as documents, photos, videos and right click. Select the share with option and select stop sharing.  When I rebooted again the permissions stayed.