# Windows 10 File-System Permissions (iTunes Folder Locked)

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, itunes, administrator, microsoft-account

I recently had a problem with my iTunes, saying it has insufficient permissions to start. I tried to see where could be possible I don't have enough permissions on my C: drive (I am an administrator using a Microsoft Account).

I do not have pictures to share, but believe me - it seemed odd. My UAC is off, and it seems like Windows ignored my configuration, asking me to continue as admin for every file-system related action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originates from not verifying your Microsoft account against your computer.

I accidentally encountered this, and it solved my problem.

I admit, this is a major issue, and I did not see any indication from Windows that I will have limited permissions for file-system and other admin related actions.

I am sorry I do not have pictures to guide you with.

To solve this:
**Start --> type 'settings' --> Accounts --> There you should see a 'You need to verify your identity on this PC'**.

There you need to complete your email address and insert the received code.
This will verify your Microsoft account against the computer and restore 'admin' state/ privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows 10. I have admin rights, checked all security rights; I right-clicked the shortcut icon for iTunes- on the bottom right was an `Advanced` button.

Click and it gives and option to `Run as administrator`; despite already being an administrator it worked.